# Gradle Distribution create File

Tags: java, gradle, properties

I'm using gradle to build a desktop app and I'm trying to create a distribution for my app. I've used the application plugin (which inherit the distribution plugin) and when I call the `distZip` task, I would like to create a file into that zip with a configuration file with values passed as arguments from  the gradle command. For ex: when I call

```
gradle build distZip --project-prop myproperty=myvalue
```

I want to generate a properties file inside the zip distribution with that content.
I've tried the following approach with no success:

```
applicationDistribution.into(".") {
    new File("server.properties").write("myproperty=$myproperty")
}
```

When I do this, it creates a file in the root of the project instead of the root of the distribution zip. Does anyone know how to create this file inside the distribution zip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be:

```
apply plugin: 'distribution'

distZip {
   def p = File.createTempFile('aaa', 'bbb')
   p.write "my.property: $project.myProperty\n"
   p.deleteOnExit()

    from(p) {
      rename {
         'server.properties'
      }
   }
}
```

and invocation:

```
gradle clean distZip -Pmyproperty=bolo
```

You need to configure the task that prepares the distribution - in this particular case `distZip` - it's task of type `Zip` (`Copy`).

Be careful with referencing properties with `project.myproperty`. If no `myproperty` is found an exception will be thrown.

Comment: If I understand well, I'll need to have the file already in my project... right?

Comment: With this construct `project.file('lol')`, yes. Because `file` method resolves file relatively to project path. Try it out with `new File('absolute path to external file')`.

Comment: this work the same way I've put in my sample. The file is created inside my project, and not in the distribution. I need the file only in the resulting zip from the distribution and not in my project.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I misunderstood it. I can't be done without temporary file. Will that suite your needs? If so I may suggest such solution later on.

Comment: It's ok to have a temporary file.

Comment: Ok, just give me some time.